# Chrome Extension - Message Passing from Popup to Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging

I'm trying to pass data from a popup to a content script, but I'm not having any luck. I got it to work the other way around (content -> popup) though. All I want to do is enter text into an input located in the popup and click a submit button which would insert that text into the dom of a web page.

This is what I have:

popup.html

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'start'}, function(response) {
    console.log('Start action sent');  
});
```

contentscript.js

```
function startExtension() { console.log('Starting Extension'); }

function stopExtension() { console.log('Stopping Extension'); }

function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == 'start')
        startExtension()
    else if (request.action == 'stop')
        stopExtension()
    sendResponse({});
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify to which tab to send to. Like this:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action:'start'}, function(response) {
    console.log('Start action sent');
});
```

If you don't know which is the tab, you can either send to all (probably a bad idea) or make the tab send info first.

For more information check this page: [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: Just want to point on that sendRequest has been deprecated since Chrome 20, and has been replaced by sendMessage, which was the reason I was having problems with this. More info in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11587062/381010