# Addon-sdk page-mod loads something strange and not actual webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I tried using a click method using content script, but couldn't manage to make it work. After some tweaking I decided to list all elements of html body and to my surprise it only loads one element

`console.log: ever: <div><br data-mce-bogus="1"></div>`

this is my script, in case I do something bad.

#### /lib/main.js

```
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
 
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://www.evernote.com/Home.action#st=p&n=*",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-1.7.min.js"), self.data.url("my-script.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
                    var newnoteHotkey = Hotkey({
                    combo: "accel-n",
                    onPress: function() {
                            worker.port.emit("clickButton", "#gwt-debug-newNoteButton");
                    }
            });
    }
});
```

I load jquery up there, but I get the same error without it

#### data/my-script.js

```
self.port.on("clickButton", function(message) {
  console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
});
```

As you see up there I posted my tweak which logs every element inside body part of HTML
what I want to achieve is run this command `$(document.getElementById("gwt-debug-newNoteButton")).click();` which should work if only I had this element loaded

Maybe the site I am loading is at fault? Evernote.com does load in a strange way

Comment: have you tried to debug this by targeting a site that is mostly static? For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have an issue: you're creating a new hotkey inside the onAttach event handler, so if this PageMod matches more than one page, your hotkey will only work for the latest one (because each time the handler gets called it creates the hotkey binding and overwrites the previous instance).

Unfortunately, Evernote website seems to load some iframes that also match the pattern you specified in the PageMod. It seems it can also happen because Workers objects seem to stick around for some past pages as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502043/addon-sdk-context-menu-and-page-mod-workers).

If you modify your main.js file a little like this

```
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var array = require('sdk/util/array');

var workerList = [];

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "https://www.evernote.com/*",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("my-script.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
    workerList.push(worker);
    worker.on('pageshow', function() { array.add(workerList, this); });
    worker.on('pagehide', function() { array.remove(workerList, this); });
    worker.on('detach', function() { array.remove(workerList, this); });
    }
});

var newnoteHotkey = Hotkey({
    combo: "accel-n",
    onPress: function() {
        for (index in workerList) {
           workerList[index].port.emit("clickButton", "#gwt-debug-newNoteButton");
        } 
    }
});
```

Because some pages may get hidden or shown and since a worker attached to a non-visible page will throw an error ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251401/3219121)), the solution is to listen to the pagehide and pageshow events so as to only keep the currently shown workers in the array.

And then in your data/my-script.js do something like this:

```
self.port.on("clickButton", function(message) {
  var button = document.querySelector("#gwt-debug-newNoteButton");
  if (button) {
      doSomethingWith(button):
  }
})
```