# Firefox add-on pageshow event fires before worker able to receive messages

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a firefox plugin and keeping track of each page's workers in an array. Apart from a bit of fancy footwork required to manage this array (as described here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686035 and here [Addon SDK - context-menu and page-mod workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502043/addon-sdk-context-menu-and-page-mod-workers)) everything is working properly. One issue I'm having is that when listening to the tabs `pageshow` event (or the worker's own `pageshow` event for that matter), the callback seems to fire before the worker is actually ready. When retrieving the page's corresponding worker in the callback and using it to try to send a message to the content script, I'm receiving the error `The page is currently hidden and can no longer be used until it is visible again.` Normally, I'd just use a setTimeout and grit my teeth, but this isn't available for add-ons. What's a suitable workaround? The code for the main part of the add-on is below:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require('sdk/panel');
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var self = require('sdk/self');
var pageMods = require('sdk/page-mod');
var ss = require('sdk/simple-storage');
var workers = [];

ss.storage.isPluginActive = ss.storage.isPluginActive || false;

var button = ToggleButton({
    id: 'tomorrowww',
    label: 'Tomorowww',
    icon: {
        '16': './icon-16.png',
        '32': './icon-32.png',
        '64': './icon-64.png'
    },
    onChange: handleButtonChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url('panel.html'),
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('panel-script.js'),
    onHide: handlePanelHide,
    width: 342,
    height: 270
});

panel.port.on('panel-ready', handlePanelReady);
panel.port.on('plugin-toggled', handlePluginToggled);
panel.port.on('link-clicked', handleLinkClicked);

pageMods.PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url('CancerDOMManager.js'), self.data.url('content-script.js')],
    contentStyleFile: self.data.url('content-style.css'),
    onAttach: function (worker) {
        addWorker(worker);
        sendActiveState(ss.storage.isPluginActive);
    }
});

// move between tabs
tabs.on('activate', function () {
    sendActiveState();
});

// this actually fires before the worker's pageshow event so isn't useful as the workers array will be out of sync
//tabs.on('pageshow', function () {
//    sendActiveState();
//});

function addWorker (worker) {
    if(workers.indexOf(worker) > -1) {
        return;
    }

    worker.on('detach', handleWorkerDetach);
    worker.on('pageshow', handleWorkerShown);
    worker.on('pagehide', handleWorkerHidden);
    workers.push(worker);
}

function handleWorkerDetach () {
    removeWorker(this, true);
}

function handleWorkerShown () {
    addWorker(this);

    // back / forward page history
    // trying to send the state here will trigger the page hidden error
    sendActiveState();
}

function handleWorkerHidden () {
    removeWorker(this);
}

function removeWorker (worker, removeEvents) {
    var index = workers.indexOf(worker);

    removeEvents = removeEvents || false;

    if(index > -1) {
        if(removeEvents) {
            worker.removeListener('detach', handleWorkerDetach);
            worker.removeListener('pageshow', handleWorkerShown);
            worker.removeListener('pagehide', handleWorkerHidden);
        }

        workers.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

function getWorkersForCurrentTab () {
    var i;
    var tabWorkers = [];

    i = workers.length;

    while(--i > -1) {
        if(workers[i].tab.id === tabs.activeTab.id) {
            tabWorkers.push(workers[i]);
        }
    }

    return tabWorkers;
}

function handlePanelReady () {
    setActive(ss.storage.isPluginActive);
}

function setActive (bool) {
    ss.storage.isPluginActive = bool;
    panel.port.emit('active-changed', bool);
    sendActiveState();
}

function sendActiveState () {
    var tabWorkers = getWorkersForCurrentTab();
    var i = tabWorkers.length;

    while(--i > -1) {
        tabWorkers[i].port.emit('toggle-plugin', ss.storage.isPluginActive);
    }
}

function handleButtonChange (state) {
    if(state.checked) {
        panel.show({
            position: button
        });
    }
}

function handlePanelHide () {
    button.state('window', {checked: false});
}

function handleLinkClicked (url) {
    if(panel.isShowing) {
        panel.hide();
    }

    tabs.open(url);
}

function handlePluginToggled (bool) {
    if(panel.isShowing) {
        panel.hide();
    }

    setActive(bool);
}
```

Comment: It seems that setTimeout is available it just needs to be required from the `sdk/timers` module. Still a pretty horrible solution though...

Answer (score 0):

try using `contentScriptWhen: "start"` in the page-mod

Comment: I am having a similar problem, changing  from `ready` to `start` did not prevent problems about the page saying it still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar problem. I think I have it working the way I want now by putting the listener in the *content* script instead of the *addon* script. I listen for the event on the window, I then emit a message from my content script to my addon script, my addon script then sends a message back to the content script with the information needed from the addon script.

In my code, I am working on update the preferences in the content script to ensure that the tab always has the most up to date settings when they are changed, only the addon script can listen to the prefs change event.

This particular snippet will listen for when the page is navigated to from history (i.e., back or forward button), will inform the addon script, the addon script will get the most up to date preferences, and then send them back to a port listening in the content script.

### Content script:

```
window.onpageshow = function(){
    console.log("onpageshow event fired (content script)");
    self.port.emit("triggerPrefChange", '');    
};
```

### Addon Script (e.g., main.js:

```
worker.port.on("triggerPrefChange", function() {
      console.log("Received request to triggerPrefChange in the addon script");
      worker.port.emit("setPrefs", prefSet.prefs);
  });
```

Since the event is being fired from the DOM event, the page must be shown. I am not sure if listening to the pageshow event in the *addon* script is doing what we think.