# Pass a textbox value in popup.html to my content script in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I need to pass a textbox value (in popup.html) to my content script when a user clicks submit in popup.html. I read many tutorials but I couldn't really understand what they did.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="MCM Username" id="username"><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" checked> ON?<br>
    <input type="submit" placeholder="MCM Username" id="sbBtn">


</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "MCMRainbowName",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Turn your name into a rainbow color on MC-Market.",
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "onoff.html"
    },

    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":["http://mc-market.org/*", "https://mc-market.org/*"],
            "js": ["rainbow.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

rainbow.js (my content script):

```
var username = "RaghavJhavar";

setInterval(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if(elements[i].innerText == username /*|| elements[i].innerText == "RaghavJhavar"*/){
            document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].setAttribute("class", "style21");
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

When the user clicks "Submit" on the popup.html, how can I send the textbox value where id="username" to rainbow.js? I want the variable username in rainbow.js to equal the textbox value with id 'username' in popup.html.

Can you please explain how to do it too?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Message Passing from Popup to Content Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108906/chrome-extension-message-passing-from-popup-to-content-script)

Answer (score 0):

In the popup script use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage to send message to the content script

In the content script use `chrome.runtime.onMessage` https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage to receive a message from background script

Please read documentation [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)